# WiX service installer gets stuck on Windows XP

Tags: service, wix, windows-xp

I have a WiX installer that installs (as a Domainadmin) a service I wrote and starts it after completion. It has to run on Windows XP as well as Windows 7. It worked fine on both operating systems.

Then I had to make a few changes to the service itself. So I made the changes, increased the version number of my installer so that it updates the service,and recompiled the service as well as its installer. I did not make any other changes to the installer.

The installer still works perfectly on Windows 7, however on Windows XP it doesn't.
On Windows XP it gets stuck somehow. The progress bar of the installation is not filling. You can't click the Cancel-Button (you can click it but then it says cancelling in the window and nothing is happening). According to the taskmanager the program is not unresponsive and you can still move the window around without a problem.

I tried to look in the installation folder of the service to see if there is some action going on but the explorer freezes if you open it. I also tried to see if the service would be already registered in the services but computer management also freezes if you open services.
There are no errors being produced in the errorlog. The CPU and RAM usage is absolutely normal.

Has anyone an idea what happend or how me making changes to the service itself broke my installer on XP?
Thank you very much for your Help.

EDIT 1/7/2013:

I only added a `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");` to main method of the service and to all Threads started by this service. That's all I changed.

It does not make a difference if you do a clean install or an upgrede.

I found out that after you kill the service and (forcefully because pressing shutdown causes the whole OS to freeze) restart the computer the Installer exits with an error telling me that I don't have sufficient privileges to install system services. I am in the administrator group. And the installer shouldn't use my account for installation anyway.
After this the installer cancels its actions by removeing the files it has added. If you restart the computer once again and try to install the service it gets stuck as described (at exactly the same step that produces the error at the first try [I noticed that throu running the installer with logging enabled as recommended by Daniel])

I furthermore found out that the installer does not remove the service from services as it cancels it's actions after the error but removes the registry entries for the service.
Ok the service is gone. The refresh yust didnt work as I expected.

Apparently the problem isn't a result of my changes at all because the version of the installer and service that worked previously now produce the exact same bahaviour!

Comment: Can you try running the installer with logging on? i.e. installername.msi -l logfilename.log

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Daniel. I will try that when I am back at work on Monday.

Comment: Looks like the service control manager may have locked up when installing the service or restarting it. It would be useful to know exactly what 'changes' you made to the service. Also does it make a difference whether you do a clean install vs an upgrade. One possiblity is that when you do the upgrade your service is not releasing an SCM handle so it causes the Windows Installer service to lock up.